# Remove white space in Json

Tags: javascript, json

How can I remove white space in the following code block and store in a javascript variable?

This is original format

```
{ "info":"First Json",
  "description":"Official Website",
  "timestamp":"1337936081",
   "rates":{
            "USD":"840", 
            "CHF":"1319", 
            "BDT":"298",
            } 
}
```

This is the format I want

```
{"info":"Central Bank of Myanmar","description":"Official Website of Central Bank of Myanmar","timestamp":"1337936081","rates":{"USD":"840","CHF":"1319","BDT":"298","SGD":"632","JPY":"1053","GBP":"887","AUD":"759"}}
```

Comment: If you wanna store in a JS variable just assign that to a variable. It's as easy as that

Comment: Why would you want to remove the white space?

Comment: The code doesn't work if I don't remove the white space.

Comment: @ChitMinThu Any good JSON parser should work whether the JSON is prettified or condensed.

Comment: this is a valid question... why was it voted down?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var jsonWithWhitespaceRemoved = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(variableWithJsonWhitespace))
```

Comment: Just what I thought when I saw the question in review queue ;)

Comment: I think this will also remove duplicate properties, which may/may not be required.

Comment: it is a dictionary so there should not be duplicate properties

Answer (score 0):

Following is screenshot to better explain the above answer:

1. open browser and press F12 to open console tab
2. paste similar code as mentioned in below screenshot
3. Run

We would get desired outcome on the right hand side.

[image]